# How to run Refactor Fields algorithm in Python console?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing

I noticed that the *Processing* algorithm, **[Refactor Fields](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_table_tools.html#refactor-fields)** has a `fields mapping` parameter. I don't think I've come across this and definitely not used it before from the Python Console.

It provides an example on how to use it:

```
processing.runalg("qgis:refactorfields",
                  input,
                  [{'name': output_field_name,
                    'type': output_field_type,
                    'length': output_field_length,
                    'precision': output_field_precision,
                    'expression': expression_based_on_input_layer
                  }],
                  output)
```

I tried to modify this in the console but I receive no output. Here is the typical code I used:

```
import processing
input = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
output = "C:/Users/Me/Desktop//test.shp"

processing.runalg("qgis:refactorfields",
              input,
              [{'name': "Value",
                'type': 0,
                'length': 10,
                'precision': 10,
                'expression': "Value"
              }],
              output)
```

Anyone know where I am going wrong? I'm using QGIS 2.12.0-Lyon with *Processing* version 2.10.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well I think I found what my problem was:

The tool does not like `input = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()`. In other words, the user must either specify the actual name of the layer loaded in the Table of Contents (especially if running in the **Python Console** of QGIS) or specify the path of the shapefile.

```
import processing

input = "C:/Users/Me/Desktop//polygon_example.shp"
output = "C:/Users/Me/Desktop//test.shp"

processing.runalg("qgis:refactorfields",
                      input,
                      [{'name': 'Value',
                        'type': 10,
                        'length': 10,
                        'precision': 0,
                        'expression': 'Value'
                       }],
                      output)
```

Note that when running the above code, the output will **only contain the field "Value"**. If you have multiple fields, you will have to repeat the above `field map` style for all fields you want kept but you could at the same time change their properties such as type and length (eg. the `Value` field from the question):

```
import processing

input = "C:/Users/Me/Desktop//polygon_example.shp"
output = "C:/Users/Me/Desktop//test.shp"

processing.runalg("qgis:refactorfields",
                      input,
                      [{'name': 'Value',
                        'type': 10,
                        'length': 5,
                        'precision': 0,
                        'expression': 'Value'
                       }, {
                        'name': 'New_Field',
                        'type': 10,
                        'length': 2,
                        'precision': 0,
                        'expression': '10'
                      output)
```

Hope this helps someone!

---

To run this on multiple shapefiles in a directory, the following could be used:

```
import glob, os, processing

path = "path/to/folder/"
for layer in glob.glob(path + "*.shp"):
    vLayer = QgsVectorLayer(layer, os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(layer))[0], 'ogr')
    processing.runalg("qgis:refactorfields",
                          vLayer,
                          [{'name': 'Value',
                            'type': 10,
                            'length': 10,
                            'precision': 0,
                            'expression': '1'
                           }],
                          path + vLayer.name() + '_refactored.shp')
```

Comment: Is that possible to use this method on more than one shapefile? For example on a folder full of shapefiles?

Comment: @Skye - Yup! Edited post to include a possible method :)